# Windows Forms App ugly fonts (blurry) on larger DPI?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, dpi

I have an issue with the presentation of standard Windows Forms application on my laptop. Specially comparing the VS designer presentation and executed application. Please refer to the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Fonts on all controls look very bad. The similar problem occurs when there is an image placed on background of the form. The image is enlarged above it standard resolution, so it's also look terrible.

I have tried different scaling configuration, but with no luck. Any ideas?

Details: Windows 10, 120 DPI (125%), VS2015

Comment: The first one worked fine for me. I have added app manifest with configuration: <dpiAware>true</dpiAware> I'm not sure how it will affect the application scaling to different DPI, but for now at least fonts are clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Select your Form, go to **Properties** and change **AutoScaleMode** property from **Font** to **Dpi**.

For more information in regards to scaling in Windows Forms, refer to MSDN article [Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605(v=vs.110).aspx).

First half explains the background behind the need of scaling and explains some of the legacy constructs.  Scroll down about half-way to [Current Support for Automatic Scaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) (or click this link).

Comment: Thanks. Frankly speaking this is the first thing that I have done. The screenshot was made when AutoScale was  set to DPI :(